# Is every simply-connected nilpotent Lie group algebraic?

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, nilpotent-groups

Say a Lie group is a *matrix group* if it is a closed Lie subgroup of some general linear group. Say a Lie group is *algebraic* if it is the group of $\mathbb R$-points of a real linear algebraic group. Clearly every algebraic Lie group is a matrix group, but the converse is false: the simplest counter-example I can think of is the group $\text{GL}_n^+$ of positive-determinant $n\times n$ invertible matrices.

By Ado's theorem and the Lie algebra correspondence, every simply-connected nilpotent Lie group is a matrix group. But one could ask for a stronger property, that such groups are algebraic. Is this true? In other words, is every simply-connected nilpotent Lie group algebraic?

Comment: I would like to add a follow-up question: if moreover the group admits a lattice (equivalently, its Lie algebra has a basis for which the structure constants are rational), does this mean that the group is moreover Q-algebraic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the answer is positive, and that it can be deduced from Theorem 3.6.3 in Varadarajan's book "Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Their Representations" which I'll state in a more concise version:

> If $\mathfrak{g}$ is a Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{R})$
> consisting entriely of nilpotent endomorphisms, then the corresponding
> Lie subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is algebraic.

Thus for your question, if $G$ is a simply connected nilpotent Lie group then as you mentioned it is a matrix group, but it is moreover a unipotent matrix group. Thus $\mathfrak{g}:=Lie(G)$ satisfies the condition of the theorem so that $G$ is algebraic.

I didn't fully look into the proof but I believe that this algebraicity is rooted in the fact that the Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff series is finite for nilpotent groups and thus polynomial.

Comment: As for the follow-up question I suggested as a comment to your post, I think the answer is positive as well. It suffices to show that $G_\mathbb{Q}$ (that is $G \cap GL_n(\mathbb{Q})$ for some fixed representation) is $\mathbb{R}$-Zariski dense in $G$ (which we now know to be $\mathbb{R}$-algebraic). And this must be true because the Lie algebra of the $\mathbb{R}$-Zariski closure of  $G_\mathbb{Q}$  is a real Lie algebra containing a full rank lattice, so it must be  $\mathfrak{g}$

Comment: very nice answer, and follow up question!